# Why does my for loop doesn't work properly (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

So this my code

```
print("Search For The News")
AnimeName=input('>')
for i in range(1,10):
    url2='https://wall.alphacoders.com/search.php?search='
    url3=url2 + AnimeName.replace(" ","+")+(f"&page={i}")
    useragent=Request(url3, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})

    print(url3)
```

I get this same results 30 times
https://wall.alphacoders.com/search.php?search=my+hero+academia&page=9

When I run this code it just repeats the same 9 instead of 2 to 9 why is it?
where am I going wrong here?

Comment: why do you expect it 2..9?

Comment: no it dosen't it just repeats the same

Comment: did not get you @rioV8

Comment: you state: `just repeats the same 9 instead of 2 to 9`, why 2 to 9

Answer (score -1):

I was unable to reproduce your error, I used this code.

```
AnimeName='my hero academy'

url2='https://wall.alphacoders.com/search.php?search='

for i in range(1,10):
    url3=url2 + AnimeName.replace(" ","+")+(f"&page={i}")
#    useragent=Request(url3, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    print(url3)
```

output is

```
https://wall.alphacoders.com/search.php?search=my+hero+academia&page=1
https://wall.alphacoders.com/search.php?search=my+hero+academia&page=2
https://wall.alphacoders.com/search.php?search=my+hero+academia&page=3
https://wall.alphacoders.com/search.php?search=my+hero+academia&page=4
https://wall.alphacoders.com/search.php?search=my+hero+academia&page=5
https://wall.alphacoders.com/search.php?search=my+hero+academia&page=6
https://wall.alphacoders.com/search.php?search=my+hero+academia&page=7
https://wall.alphacoders.com/search.php?search=my+hero+academia&page=8
https://wall.alphacoders.com/search.php?search=my+hero+academia&page=9
```

The most confusing part for me here is that you got the output 30 times, where you loop only over 10 values, pleases share the code that will reproduce that, and I'll try to help you further,